# Как правильно: _мемориал Славы_ или _Мемориал славы_?

Tags: прописная

Как правильно: *мемориал Славы* или *Мемориал славы*?

Answer (score 3):

Это не просто архитектурный памятник, это мемориал.

В таких названиях мемориальных сооружений и сборников документов, как Могила Неизвестного Солдата, Стена Плача, Аллея Славы, Курган Бессмертия, Книга Памяти , с прописной буквы пишутся первое слово и последующие слова, выражающие высокие священные понятия; но в сочетании Вечный огонь – только первое слово.

Первое слово пишется с прописной буквы по общему правилу названий памятников-мемориалов, а слово Славы - как священное понятие, поэтому корректно  "**Мемориал Славы"**, но допустимо и "Мемориал славы", если не акцентируется символичность понятия. Чаще всё-таки пишут оба слова с большой буквы, закрепляя официальное написание названия мемориала.

У Лопатина нюанс:приведённый Славой пример - не название мемориала, например:"Этот памятник стал памятником Славы", НО: В городе ... открыт Мемориал Славы (официальное название).

Comment: Да пишут-то по-разному. См. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%22&tbm=bks&start=50

Comment: А как название мемориала -- здесь:

https://books.google.ru/books?id=L8XqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%22+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&dq=%22%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%22+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=HrFPVeDxM8HmywPIioBw&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 2):

В словаре «Прописная или строчная» (В. В. Лопатин, И. В. Нечаева, Л. К. Чельцова; М., 2007)

есть

> памятник Победы, памятник Славы, памятник Неизвестному Матросу

По аналогии: мемориал Славы.